# Multiple imports from same package

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

```js
import {
  FirstLongName,
  SecondLongName,
  ThirdLongName,
  FourthLongName,
  FifthLongName,
  SixthLongName
} from 'example-package';
```

## VS

```js
import { FirstLongName, SecondLongName, ThirdLongName } from 'example-package';
import { FourthLongName, FifthLongName, SixthLongName } from 'example-package';
```

---

Are there any technical or performance related implications when you use the second option?

*(question is not about personal taste or any possible standards)*

Comment: You _must_ know that two operations is more expensive than one, right? So what is the question beyond that? Technical implications - none. I should add, the file will only be read once either way, so performance isn't an issue.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes, Im aware of that. Im not too familiar with module insides yet (caching _etc_) and was wondering if it has any impact on these things.

Comment: Not to be concerned about. The current situation is such that transpilers are used to precompile these resources in advance. So any performance implications only affect the build process. More important to be consistent - pick one and stick with it.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks mate. Make sure to submit your answer if you're interested in reputation.

Comment: of course I am :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technical implications - none. I should add, the file will only be read once either way, so performance isn't to be concerned about. The current situation is such that transpilers are used to precompile these resources in advance. So any performance implications only affect the build process. More important to be consistent - pick one and stick with it.